# Are Ghost Recon Advance Warfighter 2 servers still active?

Tags: ghost-recon-advanced-warfighter

I've been looking at getting a coop FPS that has an active community. Does anyone know if GRAW is?

Answer (score 2):

GRAW 2 is still there, but I wouldn't call it active.  Future Soldier in all of its awfulness, took over the mantle of the latest Ghost Recon game.  You will probably have better luck playing Ghost Recon Online which is in open beta right now.  Neither of them live up to GRAW 2, however.